# Create code review before commit to GitHub

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I want to upload my .diff file (from git diff) which contains what I changed for my team-mate can review it before I commit to GitHub.

How could I upload my diff file and create a review page for my colaborators?

I already google but not clear so much. Please help, thanks you!

Comment: The normal workflow is to do the work in a branch on your local copy. Commit the changes on the branch and push to a remote branch on Github.  You can review it, update it. When your all done, merge the branch into master and delete the branch. Any reason why ur not using this workflow?

Comment: Have you heard of _pull requests_ in GitHub?  If you push your branch to GitHub, and create a pull request, then your reviewer can see your entire diff with the destination branch.  This is the typical solution to your problem when using GitHub.

Comment: Thanks all, the reason is that I don't want wasting time to create and delete a branch just for reviewing source code

Comment: @LaVănThiện That's kinda the point of a branch, and it's much better than passing diffs around once you get used to it. You might have come from another version control system where branches are expensive and difficult. Git branches are extremely cheap and fast. Have a read of [Branching Workflows in the Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branching-Workflows), particularly "topic branches".

Answer (score 2):

You could put the diff in a [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/), but that would be defeating the point of Github.

Instead, you'd use a [Pull Request](https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-requests/). You'd make the changes in a branch, possibly in your own fork of the project, and submit it to the project as a Pull Request. This contains all your commits on that branch with full context. [Pull Requests have their own review system](https://github.com/features/code-review/), so others can comment. Once it passed review, the changes can be merged.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it

Comment: correct but our git hub is hooked to automated build system that builds with every PR. Is there anyway to create such diff for review purpose but not creating PR so that the build is not triggered?

Comment: @fangmobile.com Make the PR and let the build happen; builds should be cheap. If builds are costly, make the PR and manually cancel the build. Alternatively, make a fork and put the PR there where no build will happen. Alternatively, push the branch (no PR) and ask the reviewer to look at it; they can't comment on Github, but they can let you know their thoughts by some other means.

Answer (score 0):

use this command:

```
git merge --no-commit --no-ff branchname
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use ReviewBoard or any other pre commit review tool.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).